# How to load heavily loaded listview efficiently in Android [without image,bitmap]

Tags: android, android-listview, listview-adapter

I am making a Music Player for android. Everything works perfect except list-view which have like 300+ songs in it ! The activity having that list-view takes like 5 seconds to load up and I want to reduce that time to user acceptable experience. Basically I am just using song title and artist as list-view format and no image, but experience is still slow. Googled a lot and just end up with lazy loading bitmaps and smooth scrolling docs but nothing about load up time of list-view activity. Here is the code I am using -

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        vi.setTag( holder );
    }
    else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }
    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");

    }
    else
    {
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );


         holder.text.setText( tempValues.getCompanyName() );
         if (tempValues.getUrl()== null){
             holder.text1.setText("Unknown Artist");
         }
         else {
             holder.text1.setText( tempValues.getUrl() );
         }




         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));

    }
    return vi;
}
```

Another thing is when I open list-view activity thrice or more(if lucky) it goes crash(might be memory reason but not sure). Here is the Log Cat

```
12-26 01:13:59.950: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6349): getCurrentPosition: 68586 (msec)
12-26 01:13:59.960: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6349): getCurrentPosition: 68586 (msec)
12-26 01:13:59.960: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6349): isPlaying: 1
12-26 01:13:59.960: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(6349): getCurrentPosition: 68586 (msec)
12-26 01:14:00.020: D/AbsListView(6349): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-26 01:14:01.392: D/AndroidRuntime(6349): Shutting down VM
12-26 01:14:01.392: W/dalvikvm(6349): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419aada0)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349): Process: com.garaya.musicplayer, PID: 6349
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.garaya.musicplayer/com.garaya.musicplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:70)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at com.garaya.musicplayer.MainActivity.setListData(MainActivity.java:241)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at com.garaya.musicplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:186)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
12-26 01:14:01.392: E/AndroidRuntime(6349):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the Main Activity `setListData()` -

```
public void setListData()
{ 


    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];
        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver;
        metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
        metaRetriver.setDataSource(file.getPath()); 

        String filename = file.getName().replace(".mp3", ""); 
        filename = filename.replace(".MP3", "");
        String TitleFile = metaRetriver
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        String finalName;
        if (TitleFile == null || TitleFile == "") {
            finalName = filename;
        }
        else {
            finalName = TitleFile;
        }
        sched.setCompanyName(finalName);
        sched.setUrl(metaRetriver
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add( sched );
    }

}
```

Google is overflooded with Images loading and infinite list-view loading but no well result on load up time of listview. I guess Async might be helpful but I am pretty just beginner in android and its my first android app to learn how to make apps. So guyz, please help me out! I am very clueless. (If any other code is required please let me know!)

**Edited setListData() without MetaDataRetriever loads activity in 2 seconds**

```
public void setListData()
{ 


    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];
        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

        String filename = file.getName().replace(".mp3", ""); 
        filename = filename.replace(".MP3", "");

        sched.setCompanyName(filename);
        sched.setUrl("Artist");
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add( sched );
    }

}
```

Comment: Post thde layout XML of your activity. It could also be a problem there.

Comment: Its not there as on changing sdcard directory having 10 files, the activity loads like charm

Comment: Actually that has nothing to do with it. `ListView` is a very picky class and if you've configured the `ListView` layout incorrectly, `ListView` may be calling `getView()` on your adapter for each item when starting up. If this happens for 10 items, it is quick, but for 300 it will take much longer. Add debug logging to `getView()` and see how many times it is called when the activity starts.

Comment: I have tried `Log.v("EntriesActivity", position + "");` in `getView()`. It just send nearly 7 row's posiitons to Logcat which are on screen at moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself. Here is what I did -

```
public void setListData()
{ 


    for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        File file = files[i];
        final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

        String filename = file.getName().replace(".mp3", ""); 
        filename = filename.replace(".MP3", "");

        sched.setCompanyName(filename);
        sched.setUrl("Artist"); // set default value and we will get actual value via MetaDataRetriever in getView()
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add( sched );
    }

}
```

I have just remove the `MetaDataRetriever` from `setListData()` and add it in `getView()` hence lowers the burden on activity. To understand how it works just think `setListData` do work for every row and there are 300+ rows, so lots of work to do, but on other hand `getView` deals with rows which are currently on screen. So instead doing work on tones of different rows, now we just need to take care about 7-10 rows which are being displayed! So basic thing is to lower the burden on acticity as much as you ccan while seeting list-data.

Sorry for bad English ! but I hope solution works for others !

Answer (score 1):

First off, it looks like you are loading images from a URL - in other words, the internet. 5 seconds is not bad considering the source. So first, you should display a "loading" progress bar (even an indeterminate one). See here:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/07/display-indeterminate-progress-bar-on.html

Second, your URL source is failing in your logcat. Read it! In other words, your app is fine. It's the source for your data that appears to be failing (the "setDataSource" problem).

You should keep in mind that not all users will have WiFi/internet. Also, it may be slow or unreliable. Also, the datasource may or may not be available (maintenance, router issues, etc.).

Also, AsyncTask or Threads may be necessary to reduce the UI lag you mention. If you have control over the URL source, then you should be able to make calls that will return only a few rows (20 or 30) so that the users sees something quickly. Then load more rows or the remaining rows, based on data volume, traffic and user interaction.

Comment: I like your `setDataSorce` point but I am not loading any images. Please consider `setListData()` before answering, there is no `setImageBitmap()`. Another thing, that `setDataSorce` is of `MediaPlayer` I am using in my music player.

Comment: The "setDataSource" problem I'm referring to is in your logcat - so even if you aren't using, it is the problem. And I assumed you were doing internet data transfer because you have "URL" in your code. URI's are usually the name for local or remote files. Either way, if you are loading music it should be treated like images in the sense that it may take time to download before playing begins.

Comment: Well I got your point! I have removed the MetaDataRetriever (from setListData) in which there is `setDataSource` and now it loads up like 3 seconds.... Just reduced some burden from that...